# Monkeyrunner automation using Jython

Tags: android, jython, monkeyrunner

I need to automate a testing for an third party application. I've only the apk file which is installed in my emulator. Is it possible to do it through monkeyrunner? If yes can you help me out to start it with Jyton command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. To do it you have to invoke monkeyrunner, which is the jython based interpreter.

You can invoke it as

```
$ monkeyrunner script.mr
```

or with a [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29), if you are using Linux/OS X

```
#! /usr/bin/env monkeyrunner
```